# ajax on button throw exception The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I have made a form for my module with a button using AJAX callback to fill in values in multiple select form another multiple select but when pressing the button the AJAX not triggered at all and when checking the logs an exception shows with the message:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: The specified
>   #ajax callback is empty or not callable. in Drupal\Core\Form\FormAjaxResponseBuilder->buildResponse() (line 67

Here is my code:

```
public function getFormId() {
    return 'ads_admin_form';
}

public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'Place_Ads/general';
    $form['cats-wrapper'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'cats-wrapper', 'class' => ['shownselect']],
    ];
    $form['bind-wrapper'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'bind-wrapper', 'class' => ['shownselect']],
    ];
    $form['cats-wrapper']['cats'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Category'),
        '#options' => Place_AdsController::getClassifiedContentTypes(),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => '::catSelectedCallback',
            'wrapper' => 'bind-wrapper',
            'effect' => 'fade',
            'event' => 'change',
            'progress' => array(
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => NULL,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $form['bind-wrapper']['terms-wrapper'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'terms-wrapper', 'class' => ['shownselect']],
    ];
    $form['bind-wrapper']['fields-wrapper'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'fields-wrapper', 'class' => ['shownselect']],
    ];
    $form['bind-wrapper']['terms-wrapper']['terms'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Available Terms'),
        '#multiple' => TRUE,
        '#options' => NULL,
        '#size' => 7,
    );
    $form['bind-wrapper']['terms-wrapper']['addTermsBtn'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('>>'),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => '::termsSelectedCallback',
            'wrapper' => 'selectedterms',
            'effect' => 'fade',
            'event' => 'click',
            'prevent' => 'submit',
            'progress' => array(
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => NULL,
            ),
        ),
        '#attributes' => ['class' => ['bindBtn']],
    );
    $form['bind-wrapper']['terms-wrapper']['selectedterms'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Selected Terms'),
        '#multiple' => TRUE,
        '#options' => NULL,
        '#size' => 7,
    );
    $form['bind-wrapper']['fields-wrapper']['fields'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#multiple' => TRUE,
        '#title' => t('Available Fields'),
        '#options' => NULL,
        '#size' => 7,
    );
    $form['bind-wrapper']['fields-wrapper']['addFieldsBtn'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('>>'),
        //'#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
        //'#limit_validation_errors' => FALSE,
        '#attributes' => ['class' => ['bindBtn'], 'onclick' => 'return (false);'],
    );
    $form['bind-wrapper']['fields-wrapper']['selectedfields'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#multiple' => TRUE,
        '#title' => t('Selected Fields'),
        '#options' => NULL,
        '#size' => 7,
    );

    $form['bindFields'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Save'),
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'bindFieldsBtn'],
        '#submit' => ['::submitForm'],
    );
    return $form;
}

public function catSelectedCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $val = $form_state->getValue('cats');
    $terms = Place_AdsController::getsubCategory($val, 10);
    $currFields = Place_AdsController::contentTypeFields($val);
    unset($terms[current(array_keys($terms))]);
    $form['bind-wrapper']['terms-wrapper']['terms']['#options'] = $terms;
    //$form['bind-wrapper']['terms-wrapper']['#attributes']['class'] = ['shownselect'];
    $form['bind-wrapper']['fields-wrapper']['fields']['#options'] = $currFields;
    //$form['bind-wrapper']['fields-wrapper']['#attributes']['class'] = ['shownselect'];

    return $form['bind-wrapper'];
}

public function termsSelectedCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
    $selected_index = $form_state['values']['terms']['und'];
    $val = $form_state->getValue('terms');
    $form['bind-wrapper']['terms-wrapper']['selectedterms']['#options'] = $val;
    return $form['bind-wrapper']['terms-wrapper']['selectedterms'];
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    drupal_set_message('Nothing Submitted. Just an Example.');
    $new_node = array();
    foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
        $new_node[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not totally sure but I think that the problem is that both buttons (`addTermsBtn` and `addFieldsBtn`) have the same `#value`. Try to use different `#value` for the buttons or use [#name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/8.x#name) attribute for differentiate them.

Comment: Wow.. its really working now with changing the value. even if the values are kept equal and given #name attribute for each one solved the problem thanks to you @marco

Comment: Had the same problem with multiple textfields with same value but same (read: not specified) name. Giving index names to textfields helped.

Answer (score 2):

Change your callbacks to be like this:

```
'callback' => [$this, 'catSelectedCallback'],
```

Comment: not working, besides it's actually the button ajax that fire the exeption not the select ajax

Comment: Why should he? The `::methodName` notation is specifically supported by Drupal just to be a shorthand to this longer form.

Comment: For some reason it worked for me, and `::submitForm` notation didn't. So there has to be a difference.

Comment: Yes, and it's really hidden:
`[$this, 'callback']`
vs.
`'::callback'`

The difference is, that the second is not an array (no brackets)... Prone to bugs!